# Checking previous elements of string in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, numbers

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    string a;
    cin >> a;

    int index = a.find('?');


    if(a[index]-1==3)
    {
        if(a[index]-2==3)
        {
            cout << "cool" << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My so far code. I'm doing an online challenge and here is the text (translated by myself as it's in my native language).

You input a given number "N" how long your number will be. After that you input N numbers with one "?" in the number.

So, the challenge is to find whether we can form a "cool" number or not.  A lucky number is called "cool" if it contains at least 2 twos in a row (like "35225"), at least 3 threes in a row (like "353333"), at least 5 fives in a row (like "55555237"), at least 7 sevens in a row (like "777777777"), or any combination of the above (like "333522227").

My job is to write a program that will read a string S that consists of the digits 2, 3, 5 and 7 and question marks (?) and will output whether or not the question marks in S may be replaced with the digits 2, 3, 5 and 7 in order to get a cool number (each question mark can be replaced with only one digit).

The program should output "cool" if the input string can become a cool number, or "boring" otherwise (quotes for clarity).

Examples:
input

```
8
233?5757
```

output

```
cool
```

input

```
10
57?5?757?3
```

output

```
boring
```

Any advice is welcome!

Comment: Don't use `int idx = a.find(...)`. If the method can't the character it will return some garbage output and hence doing `a[index]` is undefined behavior. Did you see the answer I gave on your last question? It shows you how to initialize `index` properly.

Comment: string contains chars you can't simply compare to 3

Comment: Well, the input "always" has a "?". The website I'm using is using "?" in all test cases, therefore it won't be a problem I believe.

Comment: But remember that in real code you're not supposed to do that. :)

Answer (score 0):

`a[index - 1]` accesses the previous character in a string.

Comment: Oh.. right! I was using it after the []. However, it doesn't solve the problem still.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of things:

```
cin >> a;
```

Doesn't check that the you actually read a variable... I suggest:

```
if (cin >> a) 
{
    // use a...

}
```

Next...

```
int index = a.find('?');
if(a[index]-1==3)
```

Here, it should be `a[index - 1]`, but that's only valid if `index > 0`.  Trying to access an element < 0 has undefined behaviour - basically it means you'll get garbage results or crash.  If you use `a.at(index - 1)` the compiler will throw an exception if your code creates an invalid index - that's much safer: then you can work out why and fix your code.

Secondly, characters are stored in ASCII representation.  To get an ASCII digit 3, you need to code '3' in your program: `a[index - 1] == '3'`.

More generally, the fastest way to answer this is by scanning from right to left: if you see a digit then check if that digit starts a "cool" sequence of other instances of that same digit or '?'s.  If you scan along and can't complete a cool sequence, you can consider the non-matching character, add a count of '?'s as you back up leftwards in the string, then once you reach the start of the string of a non-'?' you can scan forward to new characters.  It's all a bit tricky, but will be the most efficient solution....